# Java mkdir + mkdirs always return false

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a new dir in Java but it doesn't work. I'm wondering why because I tried `mkdir()` first and then I tried `mkdirs()` which is supposed to create unexistant directories.

I wrote :

```
boolean status = new File("C:\\Users\\Hito\\Desktop\\test").mkdir();
// status = false
```

then I wrote

```
boolean status = new File("C:\\Users\\Hito\\Desktop\\test").mkdirs();
// status still = false.
```

A clue ?

Comment: Please format your code correctly and make sure it's compiling. `mkdir()` is a function.

Comment: For the path `C:\Users\Hito\Desktop\Test`, which directories already exist? `mkdirs()` will return false if the `Test` directory already exists, or if it lacks permission to create any of the directories that it tries to create.

Comment: If you are using Java 7 you can use [`Files.createDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html),
 which throws an exception that describes why the directory cannot be created

Comment: Why do people still write path names with double backslash?

Answer (score 1):

```
 File file = new File("C:/Users/Hito/Desktop/test");
 file.mkdirs();
 file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: with double `\\` it could ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is faster to type, and does not need double slashes:

```
boolean status = new File("C:/Users/Hito/Desktop/test").mkdir();
```

if you still get errors, check if the parent directory exists, and if file is writeable.

```
String path = "C:/Users/Hito/Desktop/";
File file = new File(path);
If (!path.exists()) {
   System.out.println("path does not exist:" + path);
} else {
   File dir = new File(path + "test");
   if (!dir.canWrite()) {
      System.out.println("dir not writeable" + path + "test");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions

Try it:

```
boolean status = new File("C:\\Users\\Hito\\Desktop\\test").canWrite();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda strange because I used the windows search and I could find my directory BUT it's not located at :

> C:\Users\Hito\Desktop

but at :

> C:\Users\Hito\Desktop\Dropbox\Stage\Applic_WIDT

which is the directory containing my application.